# Using mean value theorem to prove $x/(1+x^2)<\arctan x<x$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

Prove using mean-value theorem that $x/(1+x^2)<\arctan x<x$ for $x>0$

I got the first part but how do I prove $\arctan x< x$  using the MVT?

The first part was done easily by applying MVT on $\arctan x$, should I use $\arctan x-x$ for the second part? Thanks!

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498532/how-to-prove-for-x0-x-1x2-arctan-xx and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76437/proving-fracxx21-leq-arctanx-for-x-in-0-1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you have it. One application of the MVT gives you both parts:

Let $x>0$. Applying the Mean Value Theorem to $f(x)=\arctan x$ on the interval $[0,x]$ gives a number $c$ with $0<c<x$ such that
$$
{\arctan x-\arctan 0\over x-0}={1\over 1+c^2}
$$
Rearranging the above gives:
$$
\arctan x={x\over 1+c^2} .
$$
for some $c$ between $0$ and $x$.

Since  $x>c$ and $x\gt0$, we have: $${x\over 1+x^2}\lt{x\over 1+c^2}<x;$$
whence
$$
 {x\over 1+x^2}\lt\arctan x\lt x .
$$

Comment: thnx alot! perfect ans!