# How to prove $\frac{x}{1+x^2}<\arctan x<x$ for $x>0$?

Tags: calculus, inequality

> How to prove for $x>0$, $\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}<\arctan x<x$?

I started with saying $0<\arctan x<\frac{\pi}{2}$  when $x>0$

I'm just not sure how to proceed with this proof, it works when I take random  values but I cant see how to prove that it works for any $x$.

Comment: $$\arctan x = \int_0^x \frac{dt}{1+t^2}.$$

Comment: Often I don't post answers to elementary questions to which valid answers already appear, but often when I think the latter are more complicated than they need to be, I do. See below.

Comment: The trick is to work with the derivatives, as this makes the transcendental function disappear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For example:

$$f(x):=\frac x{1+x^2}-\arctan x\implies f'(x)=\frac{1-x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}-\frac1{1+x^2}=-\frac{2x^2}{(1+x^2)^2} $$

Since clearly $\;f'(x)\le 0\;\;\forall\,x\ge0\;$ , and in fact $\;f'(x)<0\;\;\forall\,x>0\;$ , the function is monotone descending, so

$$\forall\;x>0\;,\;f(x)<f(0)=0\;\;\text{and we're done with the leftmost inequality}$$

Now you try the rightmost inequality (very similar trick)

Comment: Right hand side would be $1/(1+x^2)$-1 which would be negative and prove the equality?

Comment: Yup, that's right...but you meant the right side's *derivative* is that expression, right?

Comment: ^yes I did, thank you

Comment: Why does it have to be the derivative instead of the normal function, wont they both work?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: what you wrote in your first comment is the derivative of the difference of both sides in the rightmost inequality. We use that since we know that the derivative is negative $\,\implies\,$ the funtion's descending...

Comment: This seems more complicated than it needs to be. See my posted answer.

Answer (score 14):

We can use the [Mean Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem):
$$
\frac{\tan^{-1}(x)-\tan^{-1}(0)}{x-0}=\frac1{1+\xi^2}
$$
for some $\xi\in(0,x)$. That is
$$
\frac1{1+x^2}\lt\frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{x}\lt1
$$

Comment: I am unable to understand how you have used the mean value theorem here. Please explain.

Comment: The first equation is an instance of the Mean Value Theorem (see the link if you do not know the Mean Value Theorem). I am assuming that it is known that the derivative of $\tan^{-1}(x)$ is $\frac1{1+x^2}$.

Answer (score 9):

\begin{align}
& \frac x {1+x^2} = \int_0^x \frac 1 {1+x^2} \, dt \le \int_0^x \frac 1 {1+t^2} \,dt \\[8pt]
= {} & \arctan x = \int_0^x \frac{dt}{1+t^2} \le \int_0^x 1\,dt = x.
\end{align}