# Prove $\frac{x}{1+x^2} < \arctan x < x ,\quad x> 0$

Tags: calculus

So I should prove $\frac{x}{1+x^2} < \arctan x < x ,\quad x> 0$

I presume easiest way would be to:

$$f(x)=\arctan x -\frac{x}{1+x^2}, \quad g(x)= x - \arctan x$$

then:

$f(x)>0$, $g(x)>0$

But now I'm not really sure what I should utilize to prove those statements

Comment: Have you seen this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498532/how-to-prove-for-x0-dfracx1x2-arctan-xx?noredirect=1&lq=1?

Comment: @StubbornAtom Oh I didn't see that, my bad

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $g(0) = 0$ and $g' > 0$ in $(0, \infty)$.

$f(0) = 0$ and $f' > 0$ in $(0, \infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Let $f(x)=\arctan x$ then apply mean value theorem for it in every interval $[0,x]$.